# Immutable collections?

Tags: c#, .net, immutability

I am making most of my basic types in my app, immutable. But should the collections be immutable too? To me, this seems like a huge overhead unless I am missing something.

I am talking about collections to hold Point3 values, etc which can be added as it goes at different times. So if there are 1M values in a collection, and you needed to delete 1 of them, you would have to create the same collection all over again, right?

Comment: There are ways to reuse the unchanging portion of an immutable collection. Stacks and lists can usually be 100% reused if you are adding to the ends, trees usually require only rebuilding O(lg n) nodes.  See my "Immutability" archive on my blog for some ideas here.

Comment: But that said: choose the tool that models your problem well. If your problem is modeled well by a mutable collection, then use a mutable collection. That is, if the collection retains its identity even upon mutation, then make it mutable. If, by contrast, you think of the collection as being an entirely different collection when it is changed, then an immutable collection makes sense.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Eric Lippert has a series on Immutability in C#, and if you read it all the way through he implements a couple different immutable collections:

1. [Immutability in C# Part One: Kinds of Immutability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability)
2. [Immutability in C# Part Two: A Simple Immutable Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack)
3. [Immutability in C# Part Three: A Covariant Immutable Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-three-a-covariant-immutable-stack)
4. [Immutability in C# Part Four: An Immutable Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-four-an-immutable-queue)
5. [Immutability in C# Part Five: LOLZ!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-five-lolz)
6. [Immutability in C# Part Six: A Simple Binary Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-six-a-simple-binary-tree)
7. [Immutability in C# Part Seven: More on Binary Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-seven-more-on-binary-trees)
8. [Immutability in C# Part Eight: Even More On Binary Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-eight-even-more-on-binary-trees)
9. [Immutability in C# Part Nine: Academic? Plus my AVL tree implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-nine-academic-plus-my-avl-tree-implementation)
10. [Immutability in C# Part Ten: A double-ended queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-10-a-double-ended-queue)
11. [Immutability in C# Part Eleven: A working double-ended queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue)

Comment: Link is broken. Working link to every entry in the series can be found here: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/immutability-in-c.

Comment: The links seem to work - they all point to MS docs so should be pretty stable

Comment: @SudhanshuMishra of course they work because the post was edited in 2020

Answer (score 16):

Immutable collections are great, especially if your app already leverages immutable types or semantics.

.NET just shipped their first [immutable collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx), which I suggest you try out.

Comment: Too bad it's for version 4.5+

Comment: Those sound good.  I'd prefer method names that make clear that they are not modifying the underlying collection (e.g. someone who sees `myList.WidthAddedItem("George");` would be more likely to recognize that a new modified list is being created and abandoned than would someone who sees `myList.Add("George");`) but otherwise they sound pretty good.  BTW, one nit about the article: `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` offers a promise that interfaces could also guarantee (for correct implementations) but the interfaces mentioned do not: that the reference *cannot* be used to modify the collection.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a collection interface method which would indicate which guarantees it could make: (1) a referenced instance allows particular modifications applicable to the collection type; (2) a reference may be passed around without the recipient being able to modify the underlying collection; (3) the collection will never be modified by anyone.  Some instances might not be able to guarantee any of the above; note that `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` guarantees 2, but I know of no interfaces that would allow any other type to make such a promise.

Comment: Also, in your performance chart, you don't mention the performance of accessing a list item by index.  If I were implementing an ImmutableList type as described, the indexing operation would be O(lgN) in general, but O(1) in some particular common cases, such as  immutable lists which were generated directly from arrays; how does that compare with what you actually implemented?

Comment: Good thoughts, @supercat. In response to your question about ImmutableList: enumeration takes O(n) time to completely enumerate. An indexed retrieval takes O(log n) time. While we do make optimizations when ImmutableList is initialized by an array, we still create a binary tree data structure out of it in order to allow efficient memory sharing with new instances when that list is mutated, whereas if we kept the array, mutating would require an entire copy. However I think we could defer the conversion till the first mutation, allowing some cases to be O(1) as you say. Very interesting idea.

Comment: Ah wait, actually no, that deferral optimization would not work -- because in the meantime the array could be changed by someone holding a reference to the original array, which would violate the immutable guarantee. So we really do need to convert the data structure immediately, which means O(log n) look up every time.

Comment: @AndrewArnott: Initializing the structure from an array would require copying the array, but starting out by making a straight linear copy of an array would not have to preclude using segments of that array to accommodate modification.  If `George` is an instance loaded from a 1,500-element array and one needs a new instance `Fred` with a different item 23, one could create a `Fred` that says, in effect, "use items 0-22 of George, then a single updated item, then items 24-149 of George".  The optimal algorithms to use would depend upon usage patterns, but I would think taking an array...

Comment: ...or enumerable type and using it to initialize an immutable object which will never be used to make a piecewise-modified copy) would seem a sufficiently common usage pattern as to be worth optimizing.  Actually, for many usage patterns, even having only a straight array-based immutable version of the type wouldn't be terrible if one regards `List<T>` as being to `ImmutableList<T>` what `StringBuilder` is to `String` (copy to mutable type, make all changes, copy back).  New versions are better, but even having a simplistic standard immutable implementation would have been better than not.

Comment: When the scenario is that you want a read only copy that you never intend to mutate, the solution is (at present) use a ReadOnlyCollection<T> and discard all references to the original list. That will get you the O(1) lookup that you're looking for. Trying to get middleground between efficient mutation of ImmutableList<T> and this fast lookup of ReadOnlyCollection<T>, while interesting discussions, will (in my opinion) make code more complex without providing any benefits that are reliable and easy to explain so that you know which is appropriate to use when.

Comment: I don't see how `ReadOnlyCollection` would be suitable for that purpose, since there's no way code which receives an instance of `ReadOnlyCollection` can communicate whether the backing store is expected to change; code which receives a `ReadOnlyCollection` could defensively copy its contents and then wrap the copy, but that would defeat the purpose of using an immutable collection in the first place.  I have some more thoughts I'd like to share; would you like to discuss them in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22160/discussion-between-andrew-arnott-and-supercat)

Answer (score 9):

My favorite trick with collections is simply to never pass them around. If they only exist inside a single object, then making them immutable is mostly irrelevant (As long as your containing object doesn't change them then they won't change).

Usually your collection represents something, right?  It's a collection of dogs or a collection of invoices...

Usually there is a thing you can do with a collection of dogs (Herd?  neuter?) or a collection of invoices (pay?)  There are virtually always operations that apply to the whole list of objects--operations that have functionality beyond the singular invoice.pay() (for instance, ensuring that the most important invoices are paid first), without a class around your collection, there is really no where to put those operations.

It also usually makes sense to have a few variables associated with your collection--and again without a wrapper you always end up putting those variables in some strange unnatural location.

It may seem strange at first but try it a couple times before you judge.

Answer (score 2):

If you only ever add/remove from the start or end you might be able to cheat - but in general; yes: the implication is that you need to create a new collection for every change.

So: do you need to (effectively) mutate collections? If so, and given their size: I'd be tempted to look at synchronizing access (rather than making them properly immutable). Look at `lock` (aka `Monitor`).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Eric's comments about choosing the right tool for the problem. Immutability adds value when your goals include providing clear identity semantics, or making your implementation easier to work with in a parallel computing environment. Immutability can also help improve performance by allowing optimizations such as caching or transparent proxying.

On the flip-side, immutability can also incur a performance cost - particularly when you use the "copy-on-write" pattern to model "changes".

You have to decide ***why*** you want your entities/collections to be immutable - and that will help drive your decision of whether to do so or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your public interface as IEnumerable, but still use a mutable collection in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A look up table would make for a decent immutable collection.  It doesn't need to change in size and you want it static so it's quick to look up tricky calculations.  If you need to add something later then I wouldn't bother with immutability, it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the style your program is written/designed.

Immutable collection do only make sense when you're programming in a functional-programming-influenced style (Imperatively designed programs shouldn't use them).

And like in functional languages, you should use Linked Lists then which can be built up in O(1) per element (`cons`) and process them functionally (recursions, building new lists from lists).

When your program requires imperative collections (arrays, vectors/lists), keep them mutable.

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on who is using the collections at the same time. Strings are immutable to prevent boo-boo's like two threads trying to remove the first char at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a collection to which you can add items after constructing it, it is not immutable

Comment: He knows that - he's asking if they SHOULD be immutable.