# Immutable set in .NET

Tags: c#, set, immutability, functional-programming

Does the .NET BCL have an immutable Set type?  I'm programming in a functional dialect of C# and would like to do something like

```
new Set.UnionWith(A).UnionWith(B).UnionWith(C)
```

But the best I can find is `HashSet.UnionWith`, which would require the following sequence of calls:

```
HashSet composite = new HashSet();
composite.UnionWith(A);
composite.UnionWith(B);
composite.UnionWith(C);
```

This use is highly referentially opaque, making it hard to optimize and understand.  Is there a better way to do this without writing a custom functional set type?

Comment: This may also be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927181/immutable-collections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

This answer was written some time ago, and since then a set of immutable collections have been introduced in the [`System.Collections.Immutable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt452182(v=vs.111).aspx) namespace.

**Original answer**

You can roll out your own method for this:

```
public static class HashSetExtensions {
  public static HashSet<T> Union<T>(this HashSet<T> self, HashSet<T> other) { 
    var set = new HashSet<T>(self); // don't change the original set
    set.UnionWith(other);
    return set;
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var composite = A.Union(B).Union(C);
```

You can also use [LINQ's `Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397728.aspx), but to get a set, you'll need to pass the result to the `HashSet` constructor:

```
var composite = new HashSet<string>(A.Union(B).Union(C));
```

But, `HashSet` itself is mutable. You could try to use [F#'s immutable set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353619.aspx).

Also, as mentioned in the comments by [ErikE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57611/erike), using `Concat` yields the same result and probably performs better:

```
var composite = new HashSet<string>(A.Concat(B).Concat(C));
```

Comment: This code doesn't guarantee deep immutability.  If you modify the set structure (e.g. what is contained in the set), the original set structure will be intact.  But if you modify items in the resulting set, the items in the original set will be changed too.

Comment: Deep immutability is only guaranteed in C# if the items in the set are immutable themselves. The set cannot enforce it on its own. Also, the `HashSet` is a mutable set, so maybe you should look for other classes outside the BCL.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: The state of an immutable set of some class-object type is the collection of the identities of the objects referred to thereby.  If I have a list of five cars' Vehicle Identification Numbers printed on tamper-evident paper, it will always refer to the same five cars.  The list should not be regarded as saying anything about where the cars are, what color they are, how many miles they've driven, etc.  All of those characteristics of cars are mutable.  The fact that many properties of a car can change, however, does not make the list of cars any less immutable.

Comment: @Jordão, supercat: For sure.  Just wanted to make it clear that putting the items in "an immutable Set type" (as the OP asked for) didn't make them magically immutable as well.  He didn't ask that question, but I feel it is a reasonable follow up thought for someone who wasn't so familiar with immutability in .Net.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: yes, that was a good point to clarify :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `new HashSet<string>(A.Concat(B).Concat(C))` and save the performance hit of materializing `A.Union(B)`, then materializing yet another `HashSet` when you `Union` C?

Comment: @ErikE: Concat != Union, they behave differently.

Comment: @Jordão You're right, they do something different! But what happens when you put duplicates into a `HashSet`? The duplicates are removed! I would challenge you to see if the result is different between these: `new HashSet<int>(new HashSet<int> { 1, 2 }.Concat(new HashSet<int> { 2, 3 }))` vs. (`HashSetExtensions`) `new HashSet(new HashSet<int> { 1, 2 }.Union(new HashSet<int> { 2, 3 }));`. They are not different--same result! Using `Concat` on many `IEnumerable`s and **once** composing a unique-item `HashSet` is less work than doing a unique item comparison again and again for each added list.

Comment: @ErikE: indeed! I'll add that to the answer. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 18):

The new [ImmutableCollections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable) have:

- `ImmutableStack<T>`
- `ImmutableQueue<T>`
- `ImmutableList<T>`
- `ImmutableHashSet<T>`
- `ImmutableSortedSet<T>`
- `ImmutableDictionary<K, V>`
- `ImmutableSortedDictionary<K, V>`

More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx)

About the union this test passes:

```
[Test]
public void UnionTest()
{
    var a = ImmutableHashSet.Create("A");
    var b = ImmutableHashSet.Create("B");
    var c = ImmutableHashSet.Create("C");
    var d = a.Union(b).Union(c);
    Assert.IsTrue(ImmutableHashSet.Create("A", "B", "C").SetEquals(d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), but it's not a hash table. LINQ adds the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) method as an extension.