# Why aren't there genuine immutable collections in C#?

Tags: c#, immutability

I am currently learning C# and I have a situation where I have a class that contains a ISet.  I don't wish clients to modify this set directly, and most clients only Add and Remove, and I provide accessors through my class to do this.

However, I have one client that wishes to know more about this set and its contents.  I don't really want to muddy the wrapper class itself with lots of methods for this one client, so I would prefer to be able to return the set itself in a immutable way.

I found I can't - well, not really.  The only options I seem to have are:

1. Return an IEnumerable (No: restrictive functionality);
2. ReadOnlyCollection (No: It's a LIST);
3. Return a copy (No: Bad form IMHO, allows clients to modify the returned collection perhaps unaware that it's not going to change the real object, plus it has performance overhead);
4. Implement my own ReadOnlySet (No: Would need to derive from ISet and thus meaning I need to implement mutators, probably firing exceptions, I would rather compile time errors - not runtime).

Am I missing something?  Am I being unreasonable?  Is my only option to provide the full set of accessors on my wrapper?  Am I incorrect in my original intent to keep the wrapper clean for the vast majority of clients?

So two questions:

1. Why isn't there an standard C# immutable Collection interface?  It seems like a fairly reasonable requirement?
2. Why is ReadOnlyCollection annoyingly called ReadOnlyCollection when it is really a ReadOnlyList?  I was going to bite the bullet and use that until I found out it was a List (and I use a Set).

Comment: Mostly answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927181/immutable-collections - see Eric Lippert's post referenced here.

Comment: The title is a little misleading: .NET *has* read-only collections, just not a read-only set.

Comment: Hard to figure out what the exact requirements are.  Sounds to me you are trying to impose behavior of the collection class on its elements.  Doesn't work, they are two distinct classes with no relationship whatsoever.

Comment: .NET just shipped their first [immutable collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx), which I suggest you try out.

Comment: Immutable collections are now part of the standard .NET libraries (.NET Core and later), and live in the [`System.Collections.Immutable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable) namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why isn't there a standard C# immutable interface? It seems like a
>   fairly reasonable requirement?

- A standard C# immutable¹ interface already exists: it's called `IEnumerable` and all containers implement it.
- More powerful immutable interfaces are problematic, because there are [many kinds of immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx). If the BCL team decided to pick one definition of immutability and elevate it to *the* immutability status it's certain that down the road people looking for a different kind of immutability would complain about the choice.

  Satisfying everyone would mean not only sorting all of the immutability mess out but creating lots of interfaces (good luck picking good names for them too) and baking all these immutability concepts into the language well enough to make immutability a first-class citizen -- remember that there are no second chances here, once you ship a public class its public interface is immutable forever (pun intended). While all of this might be good to have, I 'm really skeptical about the [cost/benefit ratio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx).
- It's not difficult to define `IReadOnlyList`, `IReadOnlySet` and such if you do require them. I assume that they do not already exist because again, minus 100 points.
- `ReadOnlyCollection` is IMHO either a concession or a class that was required internally for the BCL and exposed to the world because hey, free functionality at really low cost for the BCL team (since it would have to be implemented, documented and tested anyway). In any case I don't think that it does *not* live in the glamorous `System.Collections.Generic` neighborhood by chance.

> Why is ReadOnlyCollection annoyingly called ReadOnlyCollection when it
>   is really a ReadOnlyList? I was going to bite the bullet and use that
>   until I found out it was a List (and I use a Set).

I 'm sure the BCL team would love to be able to go back in time and fix that, because it's almost certainly one of those little inconsistencies that unavoidably sneak into any library of comparable scope. Since `ReadOnlyCollection` implements `IList` it should definitely have been called `ReadOnlyList`.

However, given that a "list" offers *more* functionality than a "collection", I don't see how this would stop you. Neither is a `Set`, so you would have to build set-related functionality on top of them in any case (which is not a good idea; just build read-only semantics on top of `Set`).

---

¹ We 're tossing around "immutable" a lot here, but that word does not have a singular meaning. I think it would be more appropriate to use "read-only", but I 'll go with your choice of word for consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand your points, although it is a pain.  Perhaps I should also clarify that I meant immutable collection particularly - but think your points probably still stand.
With regards to the ReadOnlyCollection offering more functionality than a List comment.  I should clarify, that my client would not be interested in the internal structure, only that it was a collection.  So I would be more interested in actual ReadOnlyCollection which took a Set as a constructor parameter - rather than a list.  For me to use it as it stands, I'd have to copy my set into a list first.

Comment: Just to re-clarify - a ReadOnlyCollection that wrapped ANY collection.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only interface, but there is no guarantee that an `IEnumerable<T>` is immutable.  If I had my druthers, there would have been an interface `IImmutableEnumerable<out T>`, which inherited from `IEnumerable<T>` but didn't add any new members.  Code that needed to store a sequence of items could check whether the sequence implemented `IImmutableEnumerabe<T>` and, if not, pass it to the constructor of an `ImmutableCollection<T>` type (which would in turn copy the contents to a new array which would never be exposed to outside code).

Comment: Sure, anyone could define such types in their own code, but a `Fred.IImmutableEnumerable<T>` would not be substitutable for a `Joe.IImmutableEnumerable<T>` even if they contained the exact same members.  Having such things defined in the Framework improves interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way for you to provide a read-only 'copy' of the set without actually copying the data into another instance of the same or a different structure, is to go with the wrapper and implement all the item-adding-and-removing methods to throw an exception.

If your set is exposed only as an `ISet` anyway, consumers are only going to see the members defined on the interface, no matter what your wrapper contains - that doesn't seem like it's a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

This may help,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/04/22/api-design-readonlycollection-t.aspx

Comment: BTW, while `IImmutableList<T>` might not be a bad concept, I would suggest that if one could retroactively derive a read-only interface for `IList` to derive from, it should be called `IReadableList<T>`; `IImmutableList<T>` and `IList<T>` should derive from it, but not from each other.  Note that `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` should not implement `IImmutableList<T>`, since it can promise its creator that consumers won't use it to change the underlying collection, but it can't promise consumers that the collection won't change.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it would be nice if there were better support in .net for both immutability and read-only wrappers, though I think it's important to note that there is a huge difference between the concepts.  A read-only wrapper promises its creator that consumers of it won't be able to change the underlying object, but makes no promise to consumers that the underlying object itself won't change.  By contrast, an immutable object promises its creator and consumers that its values won't change.

I'm not sure why the notion that there are many different types of immunity should be a problem.  If I have a generic `ImmutableList<T>` which takes an unqualified `T` my expectation would be that it will always contain the same `T`'s as it did when it was created.  The collection could in no way affect whether any of the properties of the `T`'s could change, and thus it shouldn't be expected to.

If I had my druthers, most of the collection-related interfaces would include readable, mutable, and immutable variants (mutable and immutable would both extend from readable).  I'd also add a write-only contravariant IAppendable interface, as well as an `IImmutableEnumerable` derived from `IEnumerable` (I'd add a `ToImmutable` method to IEnumerable (and IImmutableEnumerable); an implementation could construct an immutable collection, but in some cases that might not be the best approach.  For example, a mutable object might implement `IEnumerable` by return a mutable number of copies of a mutable element.  If the number of copies is large, converting to a simple collection could be very wasteful.